# How to split an input and check if the other side ends with a string

Tags: python

I'm working on my homework as a school student and I need to check if email is valid or not.
I have to split the input email on two sides at "@" to left and right and check if the right side ends with .com.
How can i do this?
I tried to do `elif email.split("@", 2)` but Im not sure is this correct or where to go from here.
[An image of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtutH.png)

Comment: Please do not upload an image of code. Please paste it in your question.

Comment: And if you are not sure  whether the code works as you think, you have to check it yourself by running it.

Comment: just use endswith on the original, pre-split string or the reverse indexed [-1] of the post split string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly you've done some work (although in the future, try not to post a picture) and you kinda went in the right direction.

First, if you are asking for input from a user, always check for input from the user. In this particular case, you are lucky, because by splitting by `@` and counting the number of parts, you can tell if you have an invalid email address from the get go (This is a naïve implementation, in reality it's a little trickier than that but for your level, you can assume it's enough to decide it is a viable email)

When using `split`, you need to capture the result (a list). You didn't do that in your example.

Since we only had one `@` character for a valid email, we can assume we should have 2 strings, so then it's just a case of checking the end of the second string.

```
email = input("Enter your email: ")

parts = email.split("@")

if len(parts) != 2:
    print(f"{email} is not a valid email")
else:
    if parts[1].endswith(".com"):
        print(f"{email} ends with .com")
    else:
        print(f"{email} does not end with .com")
```

Much easier than and less arduous than what you were going for. It's really worth it to think about the problem and try a few things in the future before going for the long slog you went for.

Answer (score 0):

not all email ends with `.com`, how if that email ens with `.org` for example.
I prefer using regex to validated email:

https://emailregex.com/

```
import re

def email_validator(email):
    pattern = r"""(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])"""
    is_valid = re.match(pattern, email)
    if is_valid:
        return True
    return False
    
print(email_validator("test@gmail.com"))
print(email_validator("test@gmail"))
```

Comment: Im not allowed to use regex.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).